# Hemisphere irradiance

Tags: integration, radiometry

How do I calculate sky irradiance from radiance (L) from a hemisphere above a surface which is tilted relative to the normal (x=0,y=0,z=1). I have L as a function of zenith (0 to 180deg) and azimuth (0 to 360 deg)? Any known MAtlab functions doing this kind of thing?